# Class Def Not Found for autowiring external library jar in spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application ( call it SpringApp) that depends on an external spring boot library (call it libA).

libA also depends on an external spring boot library (call it libB).

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.example"})
public class SpringApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringApp.class, args);
  }

}
```

com.example is a base packages of libA.

I have Autowired some service from libB into libA. Then I have Autowired some service from libA into SpringApp.

But I am getting NoClassFound Exception.

Comment: can you please add your maven / gradle build configuration ?  (probably the library is not configured correctly in the build so the app can not find the classes in it).   is that library on your local disk ?

Comment: Yes and I have added implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) in build.gradle dependencies

Comment: I see, I also suspected the scanBasePackages.  but as I remember, mismatch there would fail with error loading beans but not class-not-found.  so I guess it's not that also...

Comment: Which class not found?  from libA or libB ?

Answer (score 0):

According to Gradle docs, referring to local library should be done like this in the repositories section:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib'
    }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib1', 'lib2'
    }
}
```

See: [Declaring Repositories](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html)

but you mentioned using fileTree instead.